# Left Join with Blanks in B.Key

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I would like to combine two tables.
The first table (tbl1) contains all Articles I need.
The second table (tbl2) contains some additional information - but not for every article. 
That means in tbl2 are some columns where there is no value.
I am using the following join:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.c4 = tbl2.C4
```

this join filters all articles, where tbl2.c4 = ''.
But I need the total articles that are listed in tbl1.

How can I manage that?

It is based on Oracle

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: If there is no matching record in tbl2 then it will have null `''` in tbl2.c4. What you are expecting there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  I think:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT t1.*, COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
      FROM tbl1
     ) t1 LEFT JOIN
     tbl2
     ON t1.c4 = tbl2.C4;
```